# streaming data to Adobe pdf reader in android

Tags: android, pdf, streaming, viewer

I have a scenario where I need to decrypt the data and stream the data to Adobe pdf viewer to view the pdf. But Adobe pdf viewer is expecting a file uri to be sent in the intentData. I have a restriction of not storing the data on the device in unencrypted format.
Any possible solution/alternative to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a restriction of not storing the data on the device in unencrypted format.

You would first need to find a PDF viewer that natively supports whatever network protocol you are using to "stream the data". For example, if you "stream the data" in the form of an HTTP URL, you would need to find a PDF viewer that handles `http:` `Uri` values with `ACTION_VIEW`.

Then, you will need to license the source code for that PDF viewer, so you can inspect it and confirm that the viewer itself does not store "the data on the device in unencrypted format". I imagine that most PDF viewers supporting HTTP *would* cache to disk, particularly in cases where there may not be enough RAM to do otherwise. For a commercial PDF viewer, a source code license is likely to be very expensive, or simply unavailable at any price.

One approach, therefore, is to find some open source PDF viewer, so you can augment it to download the data directly and not cache it, bearing in mind that this will limit you to fairly small PDF files. Whether you can find such a viewer, and whether the viewer's rendering quality will meet your needs, and whether the open source license it is under will meet your needs, is uncertain.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.I'm using the approach you mentioned for displaying images.I tried searching open source pdf viewers available for android.But found only Android pdf viewer whose performance was not acceptable.Other open source projects like mupdf are not free.So, are you aware of any open source pdf reader that supports http: uri. I have the pdf stored on the device in encrypted format.

Comment: @Naveen: "So, are you aware of any open source pdf reader that supports http: uri." -- no, sorry.